# Is static initialization of non-final static fields safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Consider the following code:

```
public class Text {
  private static ThreadLocal<CharsetEncoder> encoderFactory =
    new ThreadLocal<CharsetEncoder>() {
      @Override
      protected CharsetEncoder initialValue() {
        return Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder().
            onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT).
            onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
      }
    };

  public static ByteBuffer encode(String string, boolean replace)
      throws CharacterCodingException {
    CharsetEncoder encoder = encoderFactory.get();
    ...
  }
}
```

Can the line that accesses `encoderFactory` in `encode()` ever throw a `NullPointerException` in a concurrent situation?

Yes, I am well aware that in this case `encoderFactory` could easily be declared as final which will make this question somewhat moot.

However, my interest here is whether the code written as above still safely publishes `encoderFactory`. If I understand the [JLS 12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4), that should be the case. The steps of static initialization do not seem to leave a possibility that any thread will see static fields in their uninitialized state (i.e. no happens-before) once it sees the class as initialized. I thought that the JLS makes it reasonably clear that static initialization forms a memory barrier.

Apparently such a `NullPointerException` has been observed, and we ended up fixing it by making this field final. While it is certainly a good thing to do, I am still puzzled how one can see a null pointer with this pattern, otherwise a much larger problem is afoot, as it could mean that any initial assignment of non-final static fields potentially may not be visible.

If the assumption that the static initialization provides a memory barrier is a reliable one (which I believe it is), I suppose that would necessarily point to a JDK bug then? Can you think of a reason that can happen other than a JDK bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be thread-safe, as per [12.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2):

> Because the Java programming language is multithreaded, initialization of a class or interface requires careful synchronization.

Initialization of a class will be safe in concurrent situations. The fields will be loaded before any thread has a chance to invoke `encode`, whether the field was declared final or not. The reference type used does not make a difference (including `ThreadLocal`).

They go further in explaining the exact steps in which initialization occurs. Threads are not notified until initialization has completed successfully or abruptly (via a thrown exception, resulting in an `ExceptionInInitializerError`).

Comment: Thanks. That's my reading as well, and I always thought that was the case. However, it appears that a `NullPointerException` was seen for that type of code. I suppose that would necessarily point to a JDK bug then? Can you think of a reason that can happen other than a JDK bug?

Comment: @sjlee Please edit the stacktrace into your question